# expanding table with observational values to a list in excel- Reverse remove duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I am trying to turn a simple table of items and the number of observations for each item into a single column of items where each items is present in the same number as the number observed in the table.

Essentially, I want the reverse of the more typical "copy-paste, remove duplicates, countif(parent data, unique value)".

In the attached example, the top example is what I imagine is the more typical desire, the bottom example is what I am looking to accomplish. I assume this will be a VBA solution, but if it can be done without, that is just as fine.

[Example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMaon.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this simple code,

```
Sub reverseDups()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
k = 1
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To Cells(i, 2)
        Cells(k, 5) = Cells(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

`Columns A and B` is your source data and you will get your output in `Column E`

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly.  I was trying something similar but it would keep cycling back up to the top (E1 in your example) for each new item (fruit).  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @KyleWolf Thats great!!